# Eclipse crash with Fedora 19

Tags: eclipse, glib

I'm trying to work with eclipse Galileo with Fedora 19.
Executing `./eclipse` loads and opens normally, but when I type some java code on the editor the application crashes and closes instantly.

This happens in the moment when the popup with the tips should appear, e.g. when you type an object instance name followed by a dot, and the Eclipse shows the possible methods.

And in the prompt appears this message:

```
GLib-GObject:ERROR:gobject.c:4127:g_weak_ref_set: assertion failed: (weak_locations != NULL)
```

I've tried to start with the `-vm` argument point to jr6, jre7 and openjdk and the error persists.

Comment: try bypassing the worksapce by `-data your_workspace_location`

Comment: Thanks for answer @Salton. Same problem using this argument.

Comment: try this: http://www.xmos.com/support/knowledgebase/xtimecomposer/xtimecomposer-studio-does-not-start-ubuntu1304